# Is it advisable to use Crystal Reports remotely with Amazon RDB

Tags: crystal-reports, amazon-rds

I'm looking into setting up a database in Amazon RDS for use with Crystal Reports. Crystal will be running in our office in California and the DB will reside in the Amazon cloud servers in Virginia. Is this advisable or should Crystal and the DB reside on the same LAN?

I have no experience with Crystal, so I don't know how data-intensive the connection with the DB is. I have used Aqua Data Studio and even SQL Server Manager from my box in California to run queries and perform operations on a SQL Server 2008 db hosted by Rackspace in Dallas. Performance was surprisingly good.

Comment: How do you know the DB is in VA? With Amazon Cloud it could be at any of their datacenters, no? I think the only way to know for sure about the performance would be to test it.

Comment: Amazon gives you a lot of control. I can specify the region when creating the DB server. I am in the process of coordinating a test with my users, but they're scattered all over. I'm hoping for feedback from people who have walked this road before.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you follow [recommend guidelines](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Designing+Crystal+Reports+off+BW+for+optimized+performance) for creating your reports data source it should work fine for you. Crystal has some idiosyncrasies (like cross-joining top level data entities if more than one is defined, or the way queries in subreports are executed), but in the end, its not all that differant from your interactive query engine from a performance perspective.